# Image cropping is not working in local workbench

Tags: tooltwist

Image cropping is not working in our local workbench (Getting WbdimageMagic error).

> 2012-11-06 12:32:34,237 DEBUG StreamGobbler - convert:ERROR >Invalid Parameter - -crop
>   2012-11-06 12:32:34,241 ERROR ImageManipulation - Error status: 4

Same thing is updated in the WbdImageMagickError.txt in the ToolTwist folder.

Answer (score 0):

The log file will usually display the ImageMagick command being used. If you run this command from the command line it might provide more useful information.

If the "-crop" parameter is not supported, check you have a recent version of ImageMagick installed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a windows-based workbench, try adding your ImageMagick bin to your environment variable PATH something like C:\tooltwist\tooltwist_win_8.0_beta\ImageMagick-\bin

Answer (score 0):

Download imagemagic from following URL:
[Link](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php#windows)
Install it in your machine.
Change the imageMagickHome path to your installation path of imagemagic in tooltwist.conf and wbd.conf files.
Restart the tooltwist workbench.